# Passing a delete method with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
      <% unless book.checkout_user_id == nil %>
        <%= link_to "delete checkout", book_checkout_path(book_id: book.id), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :class => "button", :method => :delete %>
      <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In the above code, I want to pass a parameter to my book_checkout controller. How can I make it so my destroy method will retrieve the :book_id passed in from book_checkout_path.

Then create an instance to search for a checkout with the corresponding book_id attribute rather than search by ID.

```
  def destroy
    @book_checkout = BookCheckout.where(book_id: book_id).first # this line is wrong
    @book_checkout.destroy

    redirect_to books_path
  end
```

EDIT: Added routes.
routes:

```
   book_checkout GET    /book_checkouts/:id(.:format)      book_checkouts#show
                 PATCH  /book_checkouts/:id(.:format)      book_checkouts#update
                 PUT    /book_checkouts/:id(.:format)      book_checkouts#update
                 DELETE /book_checkouts/:id(.:format)      book_checkouts#destroy
```

Comment: You can use `params` to access the GET or POST HTTP parameters given with the client's request. In your case: `where(book_id: params[:book_id])` (`params` acts like a Hash, available in Controller and Views)

Answer (score 1):

```
@book_checkout = BookCheckout.find_by(book_id: params[:book_id])
```

Since the route only has one id, I think you can use

```
book_checkout_path(book.id)
```

However, it seems strange to use the Book id to find the BookCheckout. Is there any special reason you can't do:

```
book_checkout_path(book_checkout.id)
```

and

```
@book_checkout = BookCheckout.find_by(id: params[:id])
```

Also, is it possible that both the Book id and the Book Checkout id are the same (1)? This would make it appear to succeed when it shouldn't.

Comment: I would like to find a Checkout with attribute Book_ID of 14, and search for a checkout through its attribute of Book_ID.                                                        Right now the call immediately searches for Checkout 14, not its matching attribute.

Comment: What does the route look like?

Answer (score 1):

I had to fix my original code for a workaround, but it isn't the cleanest.

```
<%= link_to "delete checkout", book_checkout_path(id: book.id, check: book.id), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :class => "button", :method => :delete %>
```

My original link_to NEEDS to pass id because my routes expect that, so I added a check which passes the attribute i will need.

```
@book_checkout = BookCheckout.find_by(book_id: params[:check])
```

In my checkout controller, I used the params[:check] instead of params[:id], because I cannot overwrite params[:id] with the book.id.